# Integrating Google reCAPTCHA with React's useFormState for Enhanced Form Security

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently working on a React project where form security is paramount. To combat spam and abuse, I've decided to integrate Google reCAPTCHA into my forms. However, I'm facing challenges incorporating it seamlessly with React's useFormState hook. My primary concern is the reCAPTCHA token's validity, which lasts only for 2 minutes after generation. I need to ensure that the token is fetched  precisely at the moment the form is submitted, right before triggering the server-side action to prevent any misuse or expiration of the token.

The useFormState hook is central to my form's logic, managing states and handling submissions. Unfortunately, I haven't found a straightforward way to integrate reCAPTCHA verification within this workflow. Directly modifying the onSubmit event with event.preventDefault() to manually handle the submission and include the token retrieval is not an option, as it contradicts the current architecture and may introduce unnecessary complexity.

I'm looking for advice, best practices, or solutions from anyone who has successfully implemented Google reCAPTCHA in a React application using the useFormState hook or a similar setup. Specifically, how can I fetch the reCAPTCHA token at the time of submission and ensure it's included in the form data sent to my server, all while keeping the form's existing structure and logic intact? Any suggestions or code examples would be greatly appreciated.